# Using different language keyboards like MacOS

Tags: keyboard, language-support

There are many questions like this one but this one is mine.

It's also different from any others that I see, even as I'm typing this up and seeing "Questions that may already have an answer."

What I would like is to have my keyboard operation something like my smartphone and something I've seen on MacOS. If I press and hold a key, instead of having the character print a bunch of times, what it'll do is show a list of options for similar characters. For example, sometimes I want to type an "o" with an umlaut like this: "ö".

Does anyone know of an program that works well on Ubuntu 14.04 and/or 14.10?

Answer (score 2):

You might try Using the Text Entry Settings. You can setup multiple languages and shift between the keyboard layouts.

[image: TextEntry1]

Click the little Keyboard Icon in the Lower Right corner under the Input sources to see what the layout for the alternate language looks like. This is the closest thing I know of that would help resolve your problem.

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, and I am aware of this, however I would like a solution closer to what I am referring to in the question. It reduces the learning curve and I think more people could be faster at using a keyboard like I describe.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Android uses key layout and character map files to achieve this. I do not consider myself an android guru so I could be wrong. Perhaps it would be helpful if you could identify the "something I've seen on MacOS" Since both MacOS and Ubuntu are *nix based operating systems a port might be available, but without knowing what I'm looking for I'm unlikely to find it.

Comment: Here's a link to info about the feature; I'm reading the article for the first time now. http://lifehacker.com/5826055/make-your-keyboard-keys-repeat-properly-when-held-down-in-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: It looks like it's call something proprietary that's not helpful to finding a Linux version of the feature: ApplePressandhold

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any program that makes the keyboard behave the way you describe, but I'd like to mention that you can type any character using its [numeric code point](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu). For instance, the code point of 'ö' is 00f6.